# Reliably finding the path to a process...Win XP, Vista and 7

Tags: vb.net, memory, process, directory

All,

I have researched the Internet and found more than a few potential solutions, but I keep getting errors on a Windows 7 machine.

Here's the scoop.  I have an application written in VB.NET that launches a console application.  The console application will run independently of my VB.NET app, so the user can close and restart the VB.NET app and potentially start a second session of the console app from the same installation.

I don't want this.  I want to identify instances of the running console app when my VB app starts, and disable the ability to run the console app a second, third,...etc. time.  But...I only want to disable this ability when the console app has been launched from the same folder as the VB.NET app.

Here's the code I'm using currently:
   Public Function CheckForConsoleApp() As Boolean
        'Check to see if console app is running in this folder.  Retrun true if so.

```
    Dim p() As System.Diagnostics.Process
    p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("MyConsoleApp")
    If p.Length = 0 Then return false

    Dim Path As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To p.Length - 1
        Dim pPath As String = p(i).MainModule.FileName
        pPath = pPath.Substring(0, pPath.LastIndexOf("\"))
        if pPath = Path Then Return True
    Next i

    Return False

End Function
```

On my system (32 bit Windows XP) this is not a problem, and it works every time.  On a co-worker's 64-bit Windows 7 machine, an error is generated that only a portion of the "ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory" can be completed.  The use of log files and other efforts have shown that the:

```
Dim pPath As String = p(i).MainModule.FileName
```

line is where the failure occurs.

Our application has to work on Windows 7, Vista, and XP machines, on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.  I've found WinAPI commands to apply read/write permissions to certain memory locations, but those were specifically used with ReadProcessMemory API commands, so I've yet to see how to apply similar commands in .NET.

Help?
Thanks,
SH

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you found your solution, but you need to set your Build Options to "Any CPU" and not X86 then it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for the solution to this problem for days...weeks even.  I gave up hope yesterday and posted a question here, and today reworded my search and found what sounds like an answer.

The gist of it is that the process looking for data on other processes is an x86 process and is trying to find data on x64 processes.  This is why my application fails.  Does anyone have a suggestion how to get around it?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/ca5fc242-fbc0-4b5b-be86-4cbd3824211b?prof=required

It's a rather long thread, but if you search for "Charl" (the name of the post's author) you'll find what I think is the answer to my question.  It may not apply to all other occurrences of the issue, but I think this is what's happening with mine.

SH